# Hyphen in subcollection name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hyphenation

I have made a mistake naming subcollection in MongoDB, unfortunately I named them using hyphen :/

Here is sample :

```
{
id: "..."

"A-Section": {
         "val":1 
       }
}
```

I need to access the "val" field. Unfortunately hyphens seems to block MongoDB.

So I have to option :

- Find a trick to access the "A-Section"
- Rename all the "A-Section"

In both case I do not know how to do it and after few researches, I only found answer if the collection name contains hyphen but not a subcollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database contains collections of documents, each document has it's own key-value pairs.

I assume you ment renaming a field in the collection and not an array inside a field.

So you can use the [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator to rename all fields in the collection

ex:

```
db.collectionName.update( {"A-Section": {$exists:true}}, {$rename: {"A-Section": 'ASection'} }, {multi: true} )
```

Comment: Just an error with the `'"ASection"'` now my collection name is `""ASection""` but worked perfectly thanks.

Comment: Oh really sorry I messed up there

Comment: You can do the same process to revert that change.